# R: Export Multiple Excel Workbooks from dataframe

Tags: r, excel, report, reporting

I have a dataframe of deals by person. I have multiple people (30+) and I want to send them a report of just their deals. Rather than manually creating 30+ individual excel workbooks, is there a package in R that can do this?

Below is my dummy data

```
df <- tibble(
  Deal = c("Deal A", "Deal B", "Deal C", "Deal D", "Deal E", "Deal F", "Deal G", "Deal H"),
  Person = c("john", "henry", "max", "felix", "henry", "john", "max", "max")
)
```

The expected result of the dummy data is to have 4 (by person) separate excel workbooks with deal data so I can send it to the people via email.

Bonus points if I can format workbooks to all have bold header and format table with $ for numbers and dates for dates!

Comment: This is easy with tidyverse's `group_walk()` function.  Write a function to create one workbook, group your data frame and pass your creation function to `group_walk()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Other packages for handling xlsx files are available
library(xlsx)
df %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  group_walk(
    function(.x, .y) {
      write.xlsx(.x, paste0(.y$Person, ".xlsx"), sheet="Sheet1")
    }
  )
```

After running this code, I see the following files in my current working directory

[image]